# How to increment all the array elements from position a to b in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have this document i mongodb.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "seats" : [ 80, 85, 90, 95 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "seats" : [ 88, 90, 92, 97 ] },
{ "_id" : 3, "seats" : [ 85, 100, 90, 85 ] },
```

I want to increment the seats array from position 1 to position 3  of the `"_id": 1` and make it to `"seats": [80,86, 91, 96]`. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a combination of both the **[`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)** update operator and the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access the elements of the seats array by the zero-based index position and increment them by one. The following **[`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)** operation uses the **[`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)** operator to increase the seats array from position 1 to position 3 of the `"_id": 1` field by 1:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 1 },
    {
        "$inc": {
            "seats.1": 1,
            "seats.2": 1,
            "seats.3": 1
        }
    }    
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update each element in the `seats` array from given index you need to loop over each element for that index and use the [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to increment the value with ["bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operation.

```js
var bulkOp = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var fromIndex = 1
var toIndex = 3

db.collection.find({ '_id': 1 }).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var seats = doc.seats; 
    for(var index = fromIndex; index <= toIndex; index++) {  
        bulkOp.find({ '_id': doc._id, 'seats': seats[index] })
              .updateOne({ '$inc': { 'seats.$':1 } }); 
bulkOp.execute();
```

Then `db.collection.find({ '_id': 1 })` yields

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "seats" : [ 80, 86, 91, 96 ] }
```